# PlatformException (PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)) while mocking method that use firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, unit-testing, mockito

I'm currently having an issue when I try to do unit test on a method that use Firestore.
This is the method that I want to mock

```
Future<MediasState> loadMedias(AbstractEvent event) async {
    late AbstractBlocState streamState;
    try {
      DataHelper _dataHelperMediasEvent = DataHelperFactory.instance
          .createInstanceFromAnotherDataHelperAndEntityInstance(
              _dataHelperEvents, event, 'medias');
      List<AbstractMedia> medias =
          (await _dataHelperMediasEvent.getAll()).cast<AbstractMedia>();
      for (AbstractMedia media in medias) {
        media.user = await (_dataHelperUsers.getEntity(media.user.get()));
      }
      medias = sortEntitiesByCreatedDateDesc(medias) as List<AbstractMedia>;
      streamState = MediasShowed(medias);
    } catch (error) {
      streamState = MediasShowedError();
    } finally {
      return streamState as MediasState;
    }
  }
```

And this the test function that I wrote

```
 test('Test load medias', () async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
    AbstractEvent event =
        EntityFactory.createInstance('Event') as AbstractEvent;

    AbstractMedia media1 =
        EntityFactory.createInstance('Media') as AbstractMedia;

    AbstractMedia media2 =
        EntityFactory.createInstance('Media') as AbstractMedia;

    AbstractMedia media3 =
        EntityFactory.createInstance('Media') as AbstractMedia;

    List<AbstractMedia> listOfMedias = <AbstractMedia>[];

    listOfMedias.add(media1);
    listOfMedias.add(media2);
    listOfMedias.add(media3);

    when(mockMediasEvent.loadMedias(event))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => MediasShowed(listOfMedias));

    blocMedias.add(LoadMediaOfOneEvent(event));

    await expectLater(blocMedias.state, isA<MediasShowedError>());
  });
```

Unfortunately I got this error when I run this test : "PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart 199:7  FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore"

The DataHelperFactory create an instance of DataHelper which need an firestore instance.

```
class DataHelper {
  DataHelper.initialize(String collectionPath) {
    this.setCollection(collectionPath);
  }

  late String collectionPath;
  late String className;
  late CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> collection;

  final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```

I already tried to upgrade my firebase dependencies but the problem is still there. I also tried on Windows and Mac device and on a friend device and I was able to reproduce the issue.
Any idea of how to fix my test will be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this post. I am trying to test my onCall cloud functions so I can use the mock libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for flutter firebase [testing](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/testing/testing/) states that mock firebase libraries need to be used. They are much easier to work with.